# Why I am not getting the dropdownitemlist2 selected value?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, webforms

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Select Country : "></asp:Label>

            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="150px">
                <asp:ListItem>*Select The  Country*</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>India</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Bangladesh</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Pakisthan</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Nepal</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
            <br />

            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Select State: "></asp:Label>

            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="150px">
                <asp:ListItem>*Select State*</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" BackColor="#0066FF" Text="Show Your Selection" Font-Bold="True" OnClick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="displayValue()" />
        </div>
         <script type="text/javascript">
             function displayValue()
             {
                 
                 alert("Country:  " + '<%=DropDownList1.SelectedValue%>' + " State:  " + '<%=DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value%>');
                 //alert("  Country: " + document.getElementByName("DropDownList1").value + "  State:  " + document.getElementsByIName('DropDownList2').value); 
             }
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

There is one code om my aspx.cs and the other is my aspx code I want to get set selected values to be printed in printed when I press the button but it only shows the the first dropdownlist value correct and the other value is the first value of the dropdownlist I am not getting the select value in dropdownlist2 pls help me fix it.

Comment: I don't see any relevant backend code, but are you using `IsPostBack` check to bind data to the DDL?

Comment: Run it in asp.net the main problem is in the js part I think.

Comment: What are the values you are expecting? Because only `Select State` is in DropDownList2.

Comment: If I select country India and  state assam in the alert it should show india and assam but its showing India and west bengal (1st item) for all the values 1st dropdown is working fine but the second is not.

Comment: You are missing AutoPostBack="True"  for the 2nd DropDownList2.

Answer (score 0):

Autopostback was false for dropdownlist2.

Comment: That's what I said!!